# How to remove paging text in excel sheet while exporting data from GridView to Excelsheet?

Tags: asp.net, paging, export-to-excel

I implemented export to excel functionality in asp.net application.Here i export data from Grid-view to excel-sheet.I also applied Paging in Grid-view.

So when i export data from Grid-view to excel sheet,paging text also display in excel sheet as shown in the given image.

[image]

How can we remove it

i follow the below approach for exporting data

**Code-Behind:**

```
Response.Clear()
Response.ClearHeaders()
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=sample.xls")
Response.Charset = ""
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls"

Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
Dim objStringWriter As StringWriter = New StringWriter(sb)
Dim objHtmlTextWriter As HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(objStringWriter)

//gvSample is Gridview server control
gvSample.RenderControl(objHtmlTextWriter)

Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.Unicode
Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble())
Response.Write(objStringWriter)
Response.End()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before rendering - disable the paging, bind the data and then render:

```
 gvSample.AllowPaging = false;
 gvSample.DataSource = ds; //Data Source
 gvSample.DataBind();
 gvSample.RenderControl(objHtmlTextWriter)
```

Answer (score 0):

when ever to get the data from database for show the gridview,before that but the result content in viewstate[""] after the reuse it. when search the data for filter the main content the updated data will present in the viewstate, so you will get correct data to export

```
gvSample.AllowPaging = false;
gvSample.DataSource = ViewState["vsData"]; //Data Source
gvSample.DataBind();
gvSample.RenderControl(objHtmlTextWriter);
```

Answer (score 0):

It works using SQL DataSourceID

```
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
{

  HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
  //To Export all pages
  GridView1.AllowPaging = false;

  GridView1.DataBind();


  GridView1.HeaderRow.BackColor = Color.White;
  foreach (TableCell cell in GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells)
  {
    cell.BackColor = GridView1.HeaderStyle.BackColor;
  }
  foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
  {
    row.BackColor = Color.White;
    foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
      if (row.RowIndex % 2 == 0)
      {
      cell.BackColor = GridView1.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor;
      }
      else
      {
        cell.BackColor = GridView1.RowStyle.BackColor;
      }
    cell.CssClass = "textmode";
  }
}

GridView1.RenderControl(hw);

//style to format numbers to string
string style = @"<style> .textmode { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>";
Response.Write(style);
Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

other attached asp coding file

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes["ondblclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(GridView1, "Edit$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
            e.Row.Attributes["style"] = "cursor:pointer";
        }
    }
```